# Unable to install the iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have tested the application on many devices, it's working fine, but i am getting a weird error while installing the same app in iPhone 8(iOS 12.1).

Refer the screenshot for better reference:

[image: Error Image]

I tried restarted the iPhone as well as the mac system, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Did you re-start the phone and reconnected to the mac ?

Comment: Did you try to reboot iPhone? I had similar warning and rebooting device fixed this

Comment: yes i did restarted the iphone as well as mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a provisioning profile issue as i was trying to install the application without registering the device. Once i registered the device, it starts working fine.

Answer (score 1):

just quit the simulator and clean your project then build and re-run your app in that if you do not have a physical device.

But if you have a physical device please reboot your iPhone and then clean project and re-run your project as above.

Hope it will work fine for you...! thank you